# Apache Ignite IgniteCompute grid computation

Tags: grid, ignite

I am using Apache Ignite v. 2.8.1 to perform parallel computations on the objects loaded in cache ( multiple nodes ).

In my client implementation I got an instance of IgniteCompute and then execute pass `IgniteRunnable` to perform my calculations:

```
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start();
IgniteCache cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("testCache");
/* load data entries */

IgniteCompute compute = ignite.compute();

compute.run(()->{ ... } )
```

Here is the problem, in my `IgniteRunnable` implementation I can iterate through the keys and update every entry I need to update, however that's not a concurrent execution that I am interested in.
I can use an `invokeAll` method of IgniteCache, but as far as I understand it also executes an EntryProcessors sequentially on correspondent entries.

What's the right way to perform concurrent computation on a subset of entries allocated to the multiple nodes in Ignite Cluster?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the [affinity compute methods](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/distributed-computing/collocated-computations#colocating-by-partition). In short, you send one compute task per partition in a cache.